# Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root. (Intellij Idea)

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, intellij-idea

I am trying to run my project (spring boot) but it is asking to configure the sdk.
But it is saying Two modules in a project cannot share the same content root.
I have installed jdk . Earlier it was working properly.
These are are the images to get the clear idea->

I am not able to do anything. Can anyone tell me what is this "same content root'
Also under the project ther are four options ->
projects
moduels
libraries
facets
artifacts
Please can someone explain this thing , I Checked on internet but didn't get clear idea specially for "facets" and "artifacts"?
This question is alreday asked but not answered properly.
Thanks in advance

Comment: This error usually appears when using Maven or Gradle in project and they has such a configuration that same directory is being used by two separate Maven modules (or Gradle source sets). This is not supported by the IDE currently. See [IDEABKL-6745](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEABKL-6745) and linked issues e.g. [IDEA-210311](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-210311) , [IDEA-214527](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-214527)

Comment: Try to close the project and the IDE, remove all `.iml` files and the `.idea` directory via the OS task manager from your project and re-import from scratch https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-or-module-wizard.html#open-project

Comment: I updated IntelliJ IDEA to version 2023.1.4 (Ultimate Edition) and I had this same issue with my existing projects. I did what @EgorKlepikov suggested and it worked.